# Symmetry of amorphous thin films

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry

I'm wondering whether amorphous thin films have point group symmetries?
Landau's *Statistical Physics Vol. I* writes:

*The highest symmetry is that of isotropic bodies (bodies whose properties are the same in all directions), which include gases, liquids and amorphous solids. It is evident that in such a body all positions in space of any given particle must be equally probable, i.e. we must have $\rho$ = constant.*

Well, he didn't say whether isotropic bodies have point groups. I can understand that, statistically, gases and amorphous solids are uniform and have high symmetry. But microscopically, there is no symmetry at all. The molecules or atoms are randomly distributed. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since no translation, rotation, mirroring, or inversion operations will result in the same structure (to the atomic level), than an amorphous solid has no point group symmetry. Having a constant average density counts for nothing in crystallography.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your comment. So, what "highest symmetry" really means is just about the symmetry of the average density function?

Comment: That seems to be the case - but isotopic isn't what crystal symmetry is about.  Remember, Landau was a theoretical physicist, not a crystallographer...